# Using Msiexec repair with transform

Tags: command, windows-installer

After instaling an msi package using transforms :

```
msiexec /i MyInstaller.msi MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=:I01
```

I want to repair this installed instance, so I try this command line:

```
msiexec /fa MyInstaller.msi TRANSFORMS=:I01
```

But I got this error:
 "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed"

My question is how to repair with msiexec this instance?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Reference the installed instance by its `[ProductCode]`:

```
msiexec /fa {????????-????-????-????-????????????}
```

where {????????-????-????-????-????????????} is replaced by the actual product code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used REINSTALL argument and it worked just fine.

```
msiexec /i MyInstaller.msi TRANSFORMS=:I01 REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=omus
```

Comment: I'm not sure of your definition of "repair", but the message "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed" means that the MSI you referred to was not the same as the one actually installed, because of a difference in PackageCode or ProductCode. So when you install with REINSTALLMODE you're not repairing - you're doing an upgrade by reinstalling that updated MSI. That's fine, except that it is an update and bot a repair.